# Trouble accessing rdf data from Sponger

Tags: virtuoso, linked-data

I am currently working on a project which uses [Virtuoso Sponger](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtSponger). I have been having multiple issues, and I have referenced a lot of material before asking these questions. Since I am new to [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), please be patient with me.

1. I cannot seem to access RDF data using this format as given on the [`Sponger` page](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtSponger) — `http://{virtuoso-host}/about/data/{format}/{URIscheme}/{authority}/{local-path}`

I tried it both on the [linkeddata.uriburner.com](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com) and the personal server I hosted with Virtuoso installed.
I wrote this in the address bar —

> `http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/about/data/xml/http://www.bbc.co.uk/music/artists/ed2ac1e9-d51d-4eff-a2c2-85e81abd6360%01artist`

— and got this error —

```
Error HTTP/1.1 404 File not found
The requested URL was not found
URI  = '/about/data/xml/http:/www.bbc.co.uk/music/artists/ed2ac1e9-d51d-4eff-a2c2-85e81abd6360artist'
```

2. When I try the HTML — 
   `http://{virtuoso-host}/about/html/{URIscheme}/{authority}/{local-path}` 
   — option of Browser input, I get much less data output from my server than from [linkeddata.uriburner.com](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com). How can I correct this?

My main objective is to get RDF data from social media and information sites, and store it in a database to be searched on locally. So for example, BBC has info on Bob Marley; so has Wiki. I get structured data from both of them, take out redundant data, and add new data so that a single object is created. I wish to query on this data from the database.

How would I store this data to the database by executing using the Browser Input method?

Also, lets say this data got stored under graphs (I saw its link in the **Virtuoso Conductor** -> **LinkedData** -> **Graph**); then how do I query on it?

Answer (score 1):

Shrivansh,

There are many issues here, so I am going to provide a broad answer.

The Sponger is going to transform a *Web Resource* into *RDF-based Linked Data*. The transformed data ends up in a *Virtuoso-hosted RDF Document*, which is identified by a *Named Graph IRI*.

Given a Web Resource URL —

> `http://www.slideshare.net/kleinerperkins/internet-trends-v1`

— you could construct an extract, transform, and load (ETL) service URL as —

> `http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/about/html/http/www.slideshare.net/kleinerperkins/internet-trends-v1`

The results of the above are as follows:

- Basic Entity Description Page (note the alternative document type links in the page footer) — http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/about/html/http/www.slideshare.net/kleinerperkins/internet-trends-v1
- Faceted Browsing-oriented Entity Description Page (again note the alternative document type links in the footer) — http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/c/9DH6GNQ6
- Named Graph IRI — http://www.slideshare.net/kleinerperkins/internet-trends-v1
- SPARQL Query Results Page — http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/c/9DJ563FL
- SPARQL Query Definition (so you can see the query source code) — http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/c/9BL763CG

When using a local Virtuoso Sponger instance, note the following:

- You have to install Sponger Cartridges for target data sources (e.g.,
  Slideshare, LinkedIn, Facebook, Twitter, etc.)
- The live URIBurner.com instance has many cartridges and meta cartridges installed and configured -- so you will see more results there than you get locally (unless you also install and enable all the asme cartridges on your local instance)
- [A list of available cartridges](http://www.openlinksw.com/c/9PZTCVU)

Comment: Thank you for the answer Kingsley, I did notice the alternate document type links and the footer and made use of them, but as explained in part 1 of the question, when I try to get the RDF data directly in N-Triples(nt) or XML(xml) format instead of the html format(in part 2) I get an error as shown. Is there no direct way to get it as an nt or xml file?
Also when we write the query how can we store the Graph in the database and retrieve it to query on it further? Inside the graphs section of Linked data I saw the links which I tried to query but they were in not a particular format.

Comment: Also when you say I need extra cartridges and need to configure them for different sites, do you mean apart from the ones I see under Sponger/Extractor cartridges in the Conductor?

Comment: To get a Turtle document use: http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/about/data/turtle/http/www.slideshare.net/kleinerperkins/internet-trends-v1

To get an RDF/XML document use:
http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/about/data/xml/http/www.slideshare.net/kleinerperkins/internet-trends-v1.

As for cartridges, I am referring to those you see in the conductor. They aren't all enabled by default since some require API keys from the API provider.

Comment: I think that when I tried the RDF/XML document use, it might have not worked because of the cartridges not being configured properly? (Hence the error as in part 1) 
Also how can I store the results in the database(rdf), and retrieve them for querying later?